# Math Domain Error when trying to do sine rule on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

```
ASide1=float(input("Enter the value of side a: "))
BSide1=float(input("Enter the value of side b: "))
Beta1=float(input("Enter the value of angle b: "))

Answer=(math.asin(ASide1*(math.sin(Beta1)))/BSide1)


print(Answer)
```

The line with answer comes back with the math domain error, would anyone be able to help me understand why?

Comment: You are trying to find `asin` of a number, for which `asin` does not exist. The number needs to be within `-1` and `+1`

Comment: Please edit your example to make it [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What input does your program take to get a math domain error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter for `math.asin()` should be between **-1 to 1**. As you can see [here](https://appdividend.com/2020/02/12/python-asin-function-math-asin-in-python/), if you exceed this range on either side you will get a `Math domain error`.

Reason for this behavior is that there isn't any `asin()` for values other than the accepted range.

Comment: No. E.g., the arcsin of 100 is ≃ π/2 + 5.2983j (Computed with Python).

Comment: @gboffi just to try your comment i did `asin(100)` and it gave me `math domain error`

Comment: And what is this check of yours going to prove? that I'm wrong or...? (hint: `import cmath`)

Comment: My answer is related to OP question, as you can see he is using `math` not `cmath` :)